# How do I use str_replace() with multiple parameters?

Tags: php

Basically, I want to use both `$city_name` and `$ref_name` with str_replace(), so that if either one (or both) of them are inputted by the user, both of them are replaced with their actual variable forms.

To give a better illustration, here's my current code;

```
$headlines = array('primary_headline' => $_POST['primary_headline'], 'secondary_headline' => $_POST['secondary_headline'], 'primary_subline' => $_POST['primary_subline'], 'secondary_subtext' => $_POST['secondary_subtext']);
$city_name = "Dallas";
$ref_name = "Facebook";
if(isset($headlines)) {
  foreach($headlines as $headline) {
      echo(str_replace('$city_name', $city_name, $headline));
  }
}
```

I'd basically like `str_replace('$city_name', $city_name, $headline)` to become `str_replace('$city_name' AND/OR '$ref_name', $city_name AND/OR $ref_name, $headline)`.

Any answers or comments will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of [str_replace() function and multiple variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007704/str-replace-function-and-multiple-variables)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question more than once. You were told exactly how to do this 11 hours ago. It's insulting to the person that already helped you (to whom you've given no feedback, no votes, nor accepted his answer) and it's insulting to the people you're now asking to write the same code you've already been given. I will not be helping you in the future.

Comment: It's not really a duplicate. The answer he'd given got me to the code above, but he really didn't answer my question as you did with much more concise code, thus I wasn't told "exactly" how to do this 11 hours ago.

Nevertheless, thanks for your help.

Comment: No, his code replaces *all* your placeholders in the text, without even having to hard code them like this. He answered this question better than I did, 11 hours ago.

Comment: Well, excuse my ignorance :(. As you may have noticed, I'm new to PHP, and what I saw in his code was a lot of overheard (for a newbie), an if statement at the end which I thought was un-needed, variable variables that I really didn't understand the use of etc. Indeed, I should have commented on answer, and I accept it being insulting to not do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$searches = array('$city_name', '$ref_name');
$replacements = array($city_name, $ref_name);
echo str_replace($searches, $replacements, $headline);
```

Comment: What is $headline? What is its purpose?